# Complex MutableMap type

Tags: types, kotlin, signature, mutablemap

I'm getting a little confused here.

So, I have a mutableMap of type

`val converters = mutableMapOf<String, Pair<KFunction<ElemBase>, x>>()`

where I can't figure out `x`

I need to add to this map several pairs based on a constructor and a method, such as:

`converters["Camera"] = ::Camera to Structure::convertCamera`

Where the first field is the reference to a constructor extending `ElemBase`, such as:

`Camera : ElemBase`

and the second is a method on the `Structure` class with a reference to a nullable `ElemBase` class:

`fun convertCamera (dest: KMutableProperty0<Camera?>)`

when `x`

`KFunction<*>` works, but I needs something more specific, where `Receiver` and argument are defined.

I tried a couple of attempts, such as

`KFunction<Structure.(KProperty1<Structure, ElemBase>) -> Unit>`

or

`KFunction<(KMutableProperty0<ElemBase>) -> Unit>`

or

`KFunction<Structure.(KMutableProperty0<ElemBase?>) -> Unit>`

I always get error whenever I try to add anything to `converters`

```
Error:(276, 9) Kotlin: Type inference failed: Cannot infer type parameter V in operator inline fun <K, V> MutableMap<K, V>.set(key: K, value: V): Unit
None of the following substitutions
receiver: MutableMap<String, Pair<Int, KFunction<Structure.(KMutableProperty0<ElemBase?>) -> Unit>>>  arguments: (String,Pair<Int, KFunction<Structure.(KMutableProperty0<ElemBase?>) -> Unit>>)
receiver: MutableMap<String, Pair<KFunction0<Camera>, KFunction2<Structure, @ParameterName KMutableProperty0<Camera>, Unit>>>  arguments: (String,Pair<KFunction0<Camera>, KFunction2<Structure, @ParameterName KMutableProperty0<Camera>, Unit>>)
can be applied to
receiver: MutableMap<String, Pair<Int, KFunction<Structure.(KMutableProperty0<ElemBase?>) -> Unit>>>  arguments: (String,Pair<KFunction0<Camera>, KFunction2<Structure, @ParameterName KMutableProperty0<Camera>, Unit>>)
```

but no lucks so far

It's interesting to notice that if I assign `::Camera to Structure::convertCamera` to a variable, I get the following type:
`Pair<KFunction0<ElemBase>, KFunction2<Structure, @ParameterName KMutableProperty0<ElemBase>, Unit>>`

But I do not have `KFunction0` neither `KFunction2`... what the hell?

Edit: found [this](https://fossies.org/linux/kotlin/spec-docs/function-types.md)

Edit2: if I manually import `KFunction0` and `KFunction2` it seems it doesnt complain anymore about them. But if I click on them, it cannot resolve..

I tried to import manually both, `KFunction0` and `KFunction2`, copying the type I saw when I assign the pair to a `var` and it looks like this is working:

`val converters = mutableMapOf<String, Pair<KFunction0<Camera>, KFunction2<Structure, KMutableProperty0<Camera>, Unit>>>()`

But not the corresponding `ElemBase` version:

`val converters = mutableMapOf<String, Pair<KFunction0<ElemBase>, KFunction2<Structure, KMutableProperty0<ElemBase>, Unit>>>()`

```
Error:(277, 9) Kotlin: Type inference failed: Cannot infer type parameter V in operator inline fun <K, V> MutableMap<K, V>.set(key: K, value: V): Unit
None of the following substitutions
receiver: MutableMap<String, Pair<KFunction0<ElemBase>, KFunction2<Structure, KMutableProperty0<ElemBase>, Unit>>>  arguments: (String,Pair<KFunction0<ElemBase>, KFunction2<Structure, KMutableProperty0<ElemBase>, Unit>>)
receiver: MutableMap<String, Pair<KFunction0<Camera>, KFunction2<Structure, @ParameterName KMutableProperty0<Camera>, Unit>>>  arguments: (String,Pair<KFunction0<Camera>, KFunction2<Structure, @ParameterName KMutableProperty0<Camera>, Unit>>)
can be applied to
receiver: MutableMap<String, Pair<KFunction0<ElemBase>, KFunction2<Structure, KMutableProperty0<ElemBase>, Unit>>>  arguments: (String,Pair<KFunction0<Camera>, KFunction2<Structure, @ParameterName KMutableProperty0<Camera>, Unit>>)
```

Although I still don't get what's going on with `KFunction*`, why they seems to not exist althought once manually imported, the compiler accept them

In case the design smells, I'm porting some c++ code here and I'd like to stick to the original structure if possible

Edit3: ok, I'll probably change design, but I'd like to find out what's going on anyway, for the sake of curiosity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write down the following code in IntelliJ:

```
val map = mutableMapOf("Camera" to (::Camera to Structure::convertCamera))
```

You can then invoke the "specify type explicitly" intention action on the assignment, or press "Ctrl + Q" on the variable to bring up its type information which is inferred.

This gets you the following:

`val map: MutableMap<String, Pair<KFunction0<Camera>, KFunction2<Structure, @ParameterName(name = "dest") KMutableProperty0<Camera?>, Unit>>>`

`KFunction0` and `KFunction2` here are the some classes that Kotlin compiles functions types to (ones that have 0 and 2 parameters, respectively). From the [*Kotlin in Action*](https://www.manning.com/books/kotlin-in-action) book:

> The Kotlin standard library defines a series of interfaces, corresponding to different numbers of function arguments: `Function0<R>` (this function takes no arguments), `Function1<P1, R>` (this function takes one argument), and so on. Each interface defines a single invoke method, and calling it will execute the function.

You can replace these with the function types instead, and remove some of the unnecessarily specific info, like this:

`val map: MutableMap<String, Pair<() -> Camera, (Structure, KMutableProperty0<Camera?>) -> Unit>>`

Since you wanted `ElemBase` to be in the type instead of the concrete `Camera` type, you can do this:

`val map3: MutableMap<String, Pair<() -> ElemBase, (Structure, KMutableProperty0<Camera?>) -> Unit>>`

However, you can't change `KMutableProperty0<Camera>` to `KMutableProperty0<ElemBase>`, since this type is [invariant](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#variance), and so this would break the assignment in your example. Just like `MutableList<T>`, it both accepts and produces its generic type, therefore it can't accept a subtype or a supertype in its generic parameter instead of the one required.